# How do I break an iPad view up into more manageable chunks?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, ipad, uiviewcontroller, model-view-controller

I know I'm probably going to be berated for not properly reading the HIG or some documentation, but after going through several training videos and building a number of small projects on the iPhone, I'm now trying to put stuff together on the iPad and, well, my brain hurts.

I understood the idea on the iPhone that one view = one screen and one view = one view controller. But now I'm dealing with a piece of hardware which can show multiple things at once, I don't really understand how I'm supposed to work with it.

The example I'll give is the current project I'm on... I've put together a bunch of different view controllers for different screens of content (splash screen, menu, article view etc). But then some of the screens have shared content. For example, the menu and the article screens both have a menu bar (like a toolbar) which slides down from the top of the screen and provides navigation. Also, I have a navigation element which is supposed to slide up from the bottom of the screen to navigate to different articles. These are things I've seen in many other iPad apps (Wired is an example).

But I'm not supposed to put more than one view controller on the screen at a time, am I? Not only that, but if I do then the autorotate functionality starts going a bit mental. But if I put everything into one view controller for one single screen, I end up with 1,000 lines of code, most of which needs to be copy-pasted into other view controllers. Seems like a pretty ugly solution to me.

So I'm obviously doing something wrong... But what should I be doing? Even if someone could please point me in the direction of the information I should be reading, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

:-Joe

Answer (score 2):

You are not forbidden to display more then one view at a time, where view controllers are just view managers residing is memory.

You can create a custom view controller to manage your view controllers. Think of it as UINavigationController or UISplitViewController.

You have an NSMutableArray of viewControllers

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *viewController;

/*
 Do not use this code in production, its just for the example
*/
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)controller inRect:(CGRect)rect {

    // check if viewcontroller is valid object
    if (controller == nil) {
        return;
    }

    // retain the controller
    [self.viewController addObject:controller];

    // position controllers view in the desired rect
    // (in your implementation you might create a zones and use them instead)
    controller.view.frame = rect;

    // you might want to provide some animation capabilities here
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
}
```

Now you can have as many views with their own view controllers on the screen as you need. You might have nested view controllers for example:
ViewControllerManager->NavigationController->[ViewControllers];

P.S. A full implementation will be more complex of course, you will need to call viewcontrollers viewWill/viewDid, manage viewcontroller view animations (presenting and dismissing), memory management on lowMemoryWarning (purging non visible or not used view controllers) and more.

Hope that helps a bit. :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion... Is the code you provided supposed to be in a UIViewController itself? I have found that if I have more than one custom UIViewController on the screen on the iPad at any one time then I get sporadic results, such as the autorotate not working correctly. However, I have discovered since that I can use UINavigationController to do a lot of the leg work...

Comment: Excuse me for my late response. Yes, it is supposed to be in your custom root view controller, from where you will manage all the children view controllers. I am also using UINavigationController as my root controller because of the same issue you have experienced. My structure is: UIWindow->UINavigationController(HIDDEN)->MyRootViewController->[menuControllers, headerControllers, baseControllers];

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are missing is that you can have confounded which are not UIViewControllers. You are quite right that UIKit expects you to display only a single UIViewController at a time (with an exception for Apple's container view controllers). However that single view controller can manage a heirarchy of many views, each of which might have a controller object managing some of their behavior. You can then reuse those controllers or custom views across many view controllers.

Comment: That's interesting, however when you say "each of which might have a controller object", how would these controller objects manifest themselves?

Comment: Just like UIViewController is a class with a `view` property you can create your own controller classes which have references to views, act as their views delegates, and generally fill the same controller role. So in your case that navigation element might be a custom view full of buttons and those buttons could call IBAction methods on some custom controller class responsible just for managing the navigation interface. That way you don't have everything talking to a single UIViewController and you can create an instance of that custom navigation controller and view wherever they are needed.